# Similar to getDOMNode in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create multiple instances of the same component but do not want it to mount again as it's children have method with fetch in them. I understand that getDOMNode would be useful in react but it hasn't been implemented in react native. I am basically asking if I can sort of use refs and render some component exactly the same without having to fetch the data for the other component. I am using a swiping view with a tab bar.

```
<View>
    <ChildrenOfSomeComponent /> // Displayed int the first tab
    <SomeComponent /> // Not displayed in the first tab
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am understanding correctly but if I am it seems like you could simply keep the state and conditionally show that view. For example:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    activeTab: 'ComponentOne'
  }
},

render: function() {
  if (this.state.activeTab == 'ComponentOne') {
    var view = '<ComponentOne>';
  } else {
    var view = '<ComponentTwo>';
  }

  return (
    <View>
      { view }
    </View>
  );
}
```

Then wherever you are switching the views at your will just have to do:

```
this.setState({
  activeTab: 'YourActiveTab'
});
```